# How to add two different business objects into the same report, so that I can bring in a calculated field into the report, in Workday?

Tags: workday-api

I have created a calculated field under the business object "Leave Request Event". I would like to add this calculated field into a report where currently the business object is just "Worker".

Is there a way to add the two different business objects into the same report, so that I can bring in my calculated field? I can see that the business objects "Leave Request Event" and "Worker" are related. However I am not sure how to practically link the two business objects to bring in my calculated field.

1. I created a calculated field within the business object "Leave Request Event". So I am not sure which data source this field now lies within, in order to be able to add the data source to the report I am working on.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xk3y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make sure you are creating an Advance Report, not a Simple report. Then you will be able to pick a secondary data source when adding the fields to the report.

Edit:

In Workday, search "bo: Leave Request Event" without quotes to search for the business object (BO) and click on it. Then, click on the Related Business Objects Tab.

The list on the left is all of the BOs that are connected to this BO. If you click on the number in the second column, it will show you all of the fields that are accessible on the related BO.

Alternatively, the list on the right shows all of the BOs that connect to this BO, and the field to reference on that BO to get to the Leave Request Event.

For your question, click on the number next to Worker in the right table and you'll see that you need to use "Leave of Absence Requests" for your related BO in the report.

Comment: Hi @WyattShipman, thanks for your response! Could we take a step back please, just because I am new to Workday, sorryy...So I created a calculated field within the business object "Leave Request Event". So I am not sure which data source this calculated field now lies within, in order to be able to add the data source to the report I am working on. I've added an image to my original question, which shows how I created the calculated field...Is there a way to know which secondary data source I need to add to my report, to be able to link the business objects together?

Comment: Any thoughts on the above?

Comment: @JedNkansa-Yeboah I've edited my answer with a response to this.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, i appreciate your explanation! Very clear!